# Permutations and Combinations, ice cream flavour edition.

Tags: permutations, combinations

I'm currently doing work on discrete mathematics in my free time and am having some difficulties with understanding some aspects of permutations and combinations. To be specific, I'm stuck on the following practice question:

```
An ice cream store sells 30 different flavours of ice cream and it offers a
choice of 3 different kinds of cones. In how many ways can we order a dozen
two-scoop ice cream cones if any two of them in one order must differ at least
by a flavor or by the kinds of cones?
```

So first I know to group each value, so there are (30 C 2) * 3 combinations of cones and flavours. For the primary portion of the question, however, I can't quite wrap my head around the wording. You want 12 cones, and they must have either a different flavour or cone type. I'm not sure what to do at this point and I think it has to do with a misunderstanding of the question. Any help with clarifying would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: We can have double-chocolate on sugar cone and vanilla and chocolate on sugar cone. The only thing we are not allowed is to have two identical cones.  You do not have the combinations of cones and flavours right. The number of combinations of flavours depends on whether order matters. Whatever you get from that, multiply by $3$ to account for the $3$ types of containers.

Comment: @AndréNicolas So if I enumerate the number of possible cones to be n = 3*(30 C 2) then would the number of possible dozen cones be n C 12?

Comment: That number is absolutely MASSIVE is why I'm not sure...

Comment: The number is indeed massive. The usual combinatorial explosion. I don't quite agree with the $\binom{30}{2}$ part. If order of scoops matters, it is $30^2$. If it does not matter, still two vanilla scoops are surely allowed, giving $\binom{30}{2}+30$ for the number of flavour combinations.